# How to configure Collapse toggle different on each element in the mapped array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a mapped array

```
const numbers = [
    {id : 1, number : 1},
    {id : 2, number : 2},
    {id : 3, number : 3},
    {id : 4, number : 4},
]
```

It's not a real one but it is similar to the array which is I have from the api
like

```
// state 
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

numbers.map((number) =>
  <Button
    key={number.toString()}
    onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
    aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
    aria-expanded={open}
  >
    click
  </Button>
```

and on click it returns

```
<div style={{minHeight: '150px'}}>
    <Collapse in={open} dimension="width">
      <div id="example-collapse-text">
        <Card body style={{width: '400px'}}>
            Some text
        </Card>
      </div>
    </Collapse>
  </div>
```

But problem is it's rendering the Collapse on each click on all the elements on the array, How can I make it unique to each element to work around.

Comment: wrapp the collapse in a componenet and use React.memo to avoid re-renders

Comment: Can you please provide your `numbers` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting one `open` state for all of `collapse` so by clicking one of the buttons all of the collapse components appear. you have to implement an open state on each collapse itself like so:

```
import { Button, Card, Collapse } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";

function Test() {
  let numbers = [1, 2, 3];
  return numbers.map((number) => <MyCollapse number={number} />);
}

function MyCollapse({ number }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        key={number.toString()}
        onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
        aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
        aria-expanded={open}
      >
        click{" "}
      </Button>
      <div style={{ minHeight: "150px" }}>
        <Collapse in={open} dimension="width">
          <div id="example-collapse-text">
            <Card body style={{ width: "400px" }}>
              Some text
            </Card>
          </div>
        </Collapse>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```